# Upload Recorded Screen Via Socket.io Not Working

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc, recordrtc

i'm trying to make a zoom/google meet clone.. and i'm using RecordRTC to record the screen and then send it the Node Server via socket.io ...sometimes i get data , and sometimes i don't,..

however i tried to do the same code with websocket ... i didn't get any problem .. always work ... that even made me wonder more,

Please help Me figure the problem where and why ... thank you..

**Server Side [Node] :**

```
const express = require('express');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const socketio = require('socket.io')
require('dotenv').config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

const server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(chalk.yellowBright.inverse.bold(`Server is Running on PORT ${PORT}`))
})

function writeToDisk(dataURL, fileName) {
    var fileExtension = fileName.split('.').pop(),
        fileRootNameWithBase = './uploads/' + fileName,
        filePath = fileRootNameWithBase,
        fileID = 2,
        fileBuffer;

    // @todo return the new filename to client
    while (fs.existsSync(filePath)) {
        filePath = fileRootNameWithBase + '(' + fileID + ').' + fileExtension;
        fileID += 1;
    }

    dataURL = dataURL.split(',').pop();
    fileBuffer = new Buffer(dataURL, 'base64');
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, fileBuffer);

    console.log('filePath', filePath);
}


const io = socketio(server)

io.on('connect', (socket) => {
    console.log("Client Has Been Connected")
    socket.emit('messageFromServer', { text:'You Are Connected To The Server!'})
    socket.on('fromClient',(data)=>{
        console.log(chalk.red.bold(data))
        if (data.data.video) {
            console.log(chalk.red.bold("Video Found"))
            writeToDisk(data.data.video.dataURL, fileName + '.webm');
        }
    })
})
```

**Client Side [Javascript]**

```
var recordButton = document.getElementById('start-recording');
var stopButton = document.getElementById('stop-recording');
var local_video = document.querySelector("#local-video")

const socketio = io('http://localhost:3000/')
console.log('Hello World')
socketio.on('connect', () => {
    console.log(socketio.id)
})


function invokeGetDisplayMedia(success, error) {
    var displaymediastreamconstraints = {
        video: {
            displaySurface: 'monitor', // monitor, window, application, browser
            logicalSurface: true,
            cursor: 'always' // never, always, motion
        }
    };
    displaymediastreamconstraints = {
        video: true
    };

    if (navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(displaymediastreamconstraints).then(success).catch(error);
    }
    else {
        navigator.getDisplayMedia(displaymediastreamconstraints).then(success).catch(error);
    }
}


function captureScreen(callback) {
    invokeGetDisplayMedia(function (screen) {
        callback(screen);
    }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        alert('Unable to capture your screen. Please check console logs.\n' + error);
    });
}



function startRecording() {
    captureScreen(function (stream) {
        mediaStream = stream;
        local_video.srcObject = stream;

        var videoOnlyStream = new MediaStream();
        stream.getVideoTracks().forEach(function (track) {
            videoOnlyStream.addTrack(track);
        });

        recordVideo = RecordRTC(videoOnlyStream, {
            type: 'video/webm',
            canvas: {
                width: 1280,
                height: 720
            },
            mandatory: {
                // chromeMediaSource: 'screen',
                minWidth: 1280,
                minHeight: 720,

                maxWidth: 1920,
                maxHeight: 1080,

                minAspectRatio: 1.77
            },
            recorderType: !!navigator.mozGetUserMedia ? MediaStreamRecorder : WhammyRecorder
        });

        recordVideo.startRecording();
        stopButton.disabled = false;
    });
}

function stopRecording() {
    recordButton.disabled = false;
    stopButton.disabled = true;
    // stop video recorder
    recordVideo.stopRecording(function () {
        recordVideo.getDataURL(function (videoDataURL) {
            var files = {
                video: {
                    type: recordVideo.getBlob().type || 'video/webm',
                    dataURL: videoDataURL
                }
            };
            const data = JSON.stringify(files)
            console.log(data)
            socketio.emit('fromClient', { "message": "Sent from client!", "data": data });

            console.log('EMIT: fromClient');

            if (mediaStream) mediaStream.stop();
        });
    });
}


recordButton.onclick = function () {
    recordButton.disabled = true;
    startRecording();
}

stopButton.onclick = function () {
    stopButton.disabled = true;
    stopRecording();
}
```

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>RealTime Record</title>

</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>Testing Recording</h1>
    </center>
    <center>
        <div class="record-action">
            <button id="start-recording">Start Recording</button>
            <button id="stop-recording" disabled>Stop Recording</button>
            <button id="fromClient">From Client</button>
        </div>

        <video id="local-video" autoplay style="border: 1px solid rgb(15, 158, 238);"></video>
    </center>
    <script src="RecordRTC.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```